# CSS - align vertical center and float right problems

Tags: html, css, sass, css-float

I have div arrow buttons on each side of the image slider that I want to have aligned vertically and the both aligned to their respective sides of their divs,left arrow aligned to left of its div, and right arrow aligned to the right of its div. My issue is that when I am using `float:right` and `line-height`, image of the arrow get vertically aligned correctly but button is not vertically aligned.

This is my html:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="large-1 columns arrow">
        <div class="button tertiary previous">
          <img src="{{ asset('/img/left-arrow.svg') }}" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-10 columns">
        <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            @foreach($issues as $issue)
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img
                  src="/imagecache/large/{{ $issue->first()->image  }}"
                  onclick="magazineDetail(
                    '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->id }}',
                    '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->name }}',
                    '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->summary ?: '' }}',
                    '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->image ?: '' }}',
                    '{{ $issue->first()->image  }}'
                    )"
                  >
              </div>
            @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-1 columns arrow">
        <div class="button tertiary next">
          <img src="{{ asset('/img/right-arrow.svg') }}" />
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This is my scss:

```
ul {
  &.button-group {
    margin-left: 0;
    li:first-child {
      width: 30%;
    }
    li:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: .7rem;
    }
  }
}
.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: inherit;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: none;
  }

  &:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  }

  &.primary {
    background-color: $purple;
    color: $white;

    &:hover {
      background: rgba($purple, 0.4);
    }
  }

  &.secondary {
    background-color: $white;
    border-color: $black;
    color: $black;

    &:hover {
      background: $white;
      border-color: $light-gray;
      color: $black;
    }
  }

  &.tertiary {
    background: transparent;
    border-color: $white;
    color: $white;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    padding: .4rem;

    &:active {
      background: $white;
      color: $black;
    }
  }

  &.narrow {
    padding-left: 2.2em;
    padding-right: 2.2em;
  }

  &.expand {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.carousel {
  margin-top: 10%;

  .carousel-nav {
    text-align: right;
  }

  .featured-magazines {
    margin-top: $global-margin;
  }

  .button.tertiary {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: normal;

    &.next {
      vertical-align:middle;
      float:right;
      line-height: 200px
    }
  }

  .all {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .swiper-container{
    text-align: center;
  }

  .arrow {
    line-height: 200px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Vertical align only works on `inline` or `inline-block` elements, not floats. if your issue is not related to this, post back your outputted code and not your dev code above - it'll be easier to debug.

Answer (score 2):

I understood your issue. Just add this CSS

CSS:-

```
.columns{
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

your arrow will be aligned vertically middle to the slider image and both right arrow and left arrow will be aligned horizontally.

Your Issue:-

[image]

After Adding My given CSS:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning for the arrows with top: 50%

You also need relative positioning on the container `row` so that the absolute positioning uses that as its anchor point.

Here's a pen of how I would set it up.
http://codepen.io/pstonier/pen/mAvgEV